# How to disallow keys other than Timestamps in DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

Pandas does not restrict DatetimeIndex keys to only Timestamps. Why it is so and is there any way to make such restriction?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":{"2019-01-01":12.0,"2019-01-03":27.0,"2019-01-04":15.0},
                   "B":{"2019-01-01":25.0,"2019-01-03":27.0,"2019-01-04":27.0}}
                 )
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.loc['2010-05-05'] = 1 # string index
df.loc[150] = 1 # integer index
print(df)
```

I get the following dataframe:

```
                        A     B
2019-01-01 00:00:00  12.0  25.0
2019-01-03 00:00:00  27.0  27.0
2019-01-04 00:00:00  15.0  27.0
2010-05-05            1.0   1.0
150                   1.0   1.0
```

Of course I cannot do

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

once again because of last two rows.
However I'd like if 2 last rows could not be added throwing an error.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slight misconception about the type of your `index`.  It is *not* a `DateTimeIndex`:

```
>>> df.index
Index([2019-01-01 00:00:00, 2019-01-03 00:00:00, 2019-01-04 00:00:00,
              '2010-05-05',                 150],
      dtype='object')
```

The index becomes an `Object` dtype index as soon as you add a different type value.  `DateTimeIndex`'s can't have types of than timestamps, the type of the index is changed.

---

If you would like to *remove* all values that are not datetimes from your index, you can do that with `pd.to_datetime` and `errors='coerce'`

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')
```

```
               A     B
2019-01-01  12.0  25.0
2019-01-03  27.0  27.0
2019-01-04  15.0  27.0
2010-05-05   1.0   1.0
NaT          1.0   1.0
```

---

To access only elements that have a valid `Timestamp` as index, you can use `notnull`:

```
df[df.index.notnull()]
```

```
               A     B
2019-01-01  12.0  25.0
2019-01-03  27.0  27.0
2019-01-04  15.0  27.0
2010-05-05   1.0   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if each index is a `pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` instance:

```
flags = [isinstance(idx, pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp) for idx in df.reset_index()['index']]
df = df[flags]
```

However, note that you can certainly do both `pd.to_datetime('2010-05-05')` and `pd.to_datetime(150)`. At least, they still result in valid datetime stamp without throwing an exception/error/

Comment: It's interesting though pd.to_datetime(150) works, in non-scalar content (like my example) it can throw error because of mixed integers and timestamps

Comment: Internally datetime stamp is int64, which I believe is the number of nanoseconds from epoch time.